# Changing the button when clicked in html and javascript.(changing add to cart button to a cart icon when clicked)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jinja2

I am having a add to cart button in html . I want to change it a cart icon if it is clicked. The ways I know can only change the styling properties but not the whole button.
Here is my button code in html

```
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-info update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

I tried adding img src when clicked using javascript onclick but that didnt work.Please suggest me a way to change it to cart icon when clicked.
Also as i am working on e-com website on django I want to defaultly show the cart icon instead of add to cart if the item is already in the cart.I think this can be done using if else.Suggest a efficint way for this if any other than if else .

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you to use fontawesome.css library

**Reasons**

1. The we use icons by adding classes
2. It cannot affect our UI design

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("icon");
   element.classList.remove("fa-cart-arrow-down");
   element.classList.add("fa-check");
}
```

```css
body{
height:100vh;
width:100%;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-outline-info update-cart" onclick="myFunction()">Add to Cart <i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" id="icon"></i>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```